# Cant copy an encrypted files after formatting a laptop

Tags: laptop, encryption

I have  questions.... 
why i cannot open my encrypted files after i formatted my laptop..?
I made a back-up in a flash drive, then when i can't copy that file on my laptop...
what should I do?? is there a way that i can copy that file... 
I already search and there's always a result about EFS... but Im not so familiar with that...

Thanks in advance to all who answer y questions! :)

Comment: What did you use to encrypt the files?

Comment: Well, that's the point of encryption. Nobody except for original owner can open that file. Original owner user doesn't exist anymore, so nobody can open that file.

Answer (score 1):

When you use EFS encryption, it created a crypto key and stored it on your computer.  That key is what is used to decrypt the EFS encrypted file.  If you wiped and reloaded the OS on your computer without saving the keyfile, the new copy of the OS doesn't know what the key is.  At this point you may be unable to open the file.